# MOJavaScriptException: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'exports.Headers = global.Headers')

Tags: javascript, sketchapp, discord-rpc

I've encounted an error of `MOJavaScriptException: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'exports.Headers = global.Headers')` while trying to import discord-rpc to my Sketch Plugin project, couldn't Googled anything related online.

**Full code**

```
import sketch from 'sketch'
const { Client } = require("discord-rpc");


export default function() {
}
```

**Full Error Message**

```
MOJavaScriptException: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'exports.Headers = global.Headers')
./node_modules/node-fetch/browser.js browser.js:23:0
__webpack_require__ bootstrap:19:0
client.js:5:22
./node_modules/discord-rpc/src/client.js __my-command.js:1047:34
__webpack_require__ bootstrap:19:0
./node_modules/discord-rpc/src/index.js index.js:6:18
__webpack_require__ bootstrap:19:0
./src/my-command.js my-command.js:2:27
__webpack_require__ bootstrap:19:0
bootstrap:83:0
```

I've tried to move the `const { Client } = require("discord-rpc");`  inside of `export default function() {}`, but no luck. changed my code to `const discord = require("discord-rpc")` is also tried.